# How to select all the checkbox but not one with some id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with one checkbox per line, i want to select all the checkbox with jQuery but not the first which  has id='selectAll'

How can i achieve that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not('#selectAll')
```

Alternatively, to select all checkbox except the first, you might also use [gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:gt(0)')
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many way of doing it..

```
$(':checkbox', '#tableID').filter(function () {
   return this.id != 'selectAll'; 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not('#id')
```